# CPython loops optimization

Tags: python, optimization, compilation, cpython

Can someone explain to me why CPython doesn't have optimization for loops like loop-invariant optimization?
for example:

```
for i in range(100000000000):
    pass
```

cpython doesn't skip the loop and take some time to complete the execution;
this will happen with while loop too.

Comment: which version of cpython

Comment: I could change the value of `range` so that the loop does something.

Comment: There's quite some literature on the general topic of Python optimization. This resource might be a good start: http://faster-cpython.readthedocs.io/index.html

Comment: thanks for the link bruno

Answer (score 5):

Because python has no idea what `range` is until you run the loop since builtins can be overrided. If I do

```
class range:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        global x 
        x = 0
    def __iter__(self):
       global x
       while x < self.n:
           yield x
           x += 1

for i in range(20): pass
print(x)  # prints 20
```

you can see that it's hard to optimise things like that in a dynamic language

Comment: yes i understand that but this will happen with while loops too and they cannot be ovverided.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. How could a while loop be optimised?

Comment: If has sense with "for" why "while" couldn't make sense? all static compilers that.

Comment: All static compilers what?

Comment: Note that it could *technically* compare the `tp_next` (the name may be wrong, I don't know it by heart) member of the object with a list of built-in side-effects-free implementations, but it would make the code much more complex for a *very* unlikely scenario. Since you're comparing what are essentially static pointers to implementations rather than names you don't have problems of dynamism. But again, pointless and hard, and it introduces overhead for the actually likely cases.

Comment: However, it'd still need to generate the bytecode for both cases, because of the mentioned dynamism.